# Neural Network Evaluation and Topology

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, topology

My goal is to solve the XOR problem using a Neural Network. I’ve read countless articles on the theory, proof, and mathematics behind a multi-layered neural network. The theory make sense (math… not so much) but I have a few simple questions regarding the evaluation and topology of a Neural Network.

I feel I am very close to solving this problem, but I am beginning to question my topology and evaluation techniques. The complexities of back propagation aside, I just want to know if my approach to evaluation is correct. With that in mind, here are my questions:

1. Assuming we have multiple inputs, does each respective input get its’ own node? Do we ever input both values into a single node? Does the order in which we enter this information matter?
2. While evaluating the graph output, does each node fire as soon as it gets a value? Or do we instead collect all the values from the above layer and then fire off once we’ve consumed all the input?
3. Does the order of evaluation matter? For example, if a given node in layer “b” is ready to fire – but other nodes in that same layer are still awaiting input – should the ready node fire anyway? Or should all nodes in the layer be loaded up before firing?
4. Should each layer be connected to all nodes in the following layer?

[image]

I’ve attached a picture which should help explain (some of) my questions.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Interesting: an only demo that shows how a neural-network is evolved to act as an XOR gate https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/evolvexor/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, each input gets its own node, and that node is always the node for that input type. The order doesn't matter - you just need to keep it consistent. After all, an untrained neural net can learn to map any set of linearly separable inputs to outputs, so there can't be an order that you need to put the nodes in in order for it to work.

2 and 3) You need to collect all the values from a single layer before any node in the next layer fires. This is important if you're using any activation function other than a stepwise one, because the sum of the inputs will affect the value that is propagated forward. Thus, you need to know what that sum is before you propagate anything.

4) Which nodes to connect to which other nodes is up to you. Since your net won't be excessively large and XOR is a fairly straightforward problem, it will probably be simplest for you to connect all nodes in one layer to all nodes in the next layer (i.e. a fully-connected neural net). There might be specialized cases in other problems where it would be better to not use this topology, but there isn't an easy way to figure it out (most people either use trial and error or a genetic algorithm, as in NEAT), and you don't need to worry about it for the purposes of this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and good information! Although simple questions, you'd be surprised how much of this type of thing is not really well defined :) I appreciate your response.

Comment: With the use of NEAT, new (hidden) nodes introduced via mutation are not separated into levels. The result is that there can be loops/cycles/recurrence in the way the hidden nodes are connected. How is this handled during evaluation?